# WCF deserializing body error because of adding async behind the method name

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, xamarin, wcf-binding, synchronous

I've created a WCF service with a method `GetTestValue`. I've also created a test application to test this service.

When I add this WCF service with connected service to the test application I can only call `GetTestValueAsync`, there is no `GetTestValue` method. Somehow this add process add this async thing behind the method name. So in this test application, the WCF call works fine when I call `GetTestValueAsync`. I get the result back.

Then I've created a Xamarin cross application app where I added this WCF service too, and when I call the `GetTestValueAsync` from this application I get the following error:

> Error in deserializing body of request message for operation '**GetTestValue**'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'GetTestValue' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name '**GetTestValueAsync**' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'

Somehow strange in the test project it works fine, and in the Xamarin cross application not.

1. Did someone have the same problem?
2. Why is this connected service always this `Async` to my method name?

How can I stop this `Async` being added to the method name?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Xamarin apps aren't compatible with the Task-based asynchronous WCF proxy methods that the [WCF Web Service Reference](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/Documentation/WCF-Web-Service-Reference-guide.md) connected service provider generates (bugzilla.xamarin.com [Bug 51959](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51959)).

One way to generate an older, compatible style of WCF proxy methods is to run [`SvcUtil.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) with the `/async` and `/tcv:Version35` switches in a [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs). That will generate synchronous proxy methods, Begin/End style Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) callback proxy methods, and event-based proxy methods, all of which are compatible with Xamarin apps.

(Note: If you leave out the `/async` switch, `SvcUtil.exe` will generate the newer, incompatible Task-based proxy methods.)

*Duplicate*: By chance, I replied on a more recent duplicate of this question first:
 [How to use WCF services in .netstandard with Xamarin.Forms project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989563/how-to-use-wcf-services-in-netstandard-with-xamarin-forms-project)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had the same problem and searched a while. When you are adding the Reference in your project, you can check "generate synchronized operations" and the "Async"-suffix aren't generated anymore. My VS runs in german language, so I just translated the options. If your adding new methods the setting will be considered too.

Greetings from germany.