# How to use WCF services in .netstandard with Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I've created a Xamarin.Forms project with .netstandard 2.0 as PCL project. I'm trying to consume WCF services in that project. I've added the connected service for WCF service. When I'm trying to call any method provided in the service, it gives the error as below:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Error in deserializing body of
>   request message for operation 'GetData'. OperationFormatter
>   encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type
>   'Element' with name 'GetData' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'.
>   Found node type 'Element' with name 'GetDataAsync' and namespace
>   'http://tempuri.org/'

I've also tried to change the .netstandard version to an older version but it gives the same error.

Comment: The error suggests the shape of the body is incorrect, rather than a method not implemented.  Are the models correct?

Comment: @Neil yes the models are correct. Actually the method GetData may have the problem with the proxy classes generated by the WCF service provider in Visual Studio

Comment: Hi there! Does anyone know if Xamarin will be compatible with Task-based asynchronous WCF proxy methods? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @Ignacio I think it'll take time as there is no news for its implementation for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment Xamarin apps aren't compatible with the Task-based asynchronous WCF proxy methods that the [WCF Web Service Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) connected service provider generates for .NET Standard projects (bugzilla.xamarin.com [Bug 51959](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51959)).

One way to generate an older, compatible style of WCF proxy methods is to run [`SvcUtil.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) with the `/async` and `/tcv:Version35` switches in a [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs). That will generate synchronous proxy methods, Begin/End style Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) callback proxy methods, and event-based proxy methods, all of which are compatible with Xamarin apps.

(Note: If you leave out the `/async` switch, `SvcUtil.exe` will generate the newer, incompatible Task-based proxy methods.)

Comment: I think, there is no option to generate the proxy classes using the old option as Visual studio 2017 svcutil.exe again generates the async/await style proxy methods

Comment: Hmm. You can perhaps try explicitly passing the `/tcv:Version35` option as well. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe): "When using `/tcv:Version35` with the `/async` switch, both event-based and callback/delegate-based asynchronous methods are generated." In my quick tests with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\SvcUtil.exe`, I got the desired callback and event-based methods.

Comment: Ah ha. It seems that if you leave out the `/async` flag it now includes the Task-based methods by default alongside the synchronous methods. I'll edit my answer a bit to account for this and to mention the `/tcv:Version35` flag as well since that's required to get the event-based methods.

Comment: @BrendanZagaeski I just generated a `Reference.cs` file using the `svcutil` and added it to my `.Net Standard 1.4` project but got the error: " The type or namespace name 'IExtensibleDataObject' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization'" do you have any idea what could be causing this? I've looked all over the internet for that reference but can't see it

Comment: It looks like the type `IExtensibleDataObject` is [not available in .NET Standard 1.4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject?view=netstandard-1.4). The type [_is_ available in .NET Standard 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject?view=netstandard-2.0), if switching to that target framework is an option for you. "WCF Web Service Reference" proxies seem to discard properties that use that type, so another option might be to edit out the affected properties from the `SvcUtil` proxy

Answer (score 3):

Generate an older compatible style of WCF proxy methods via checked "Generate Synchronous Operations" checkbox on Configure WCF Web Service Reference screen:

[image: Generate Synchronous Operations]

Consume the web service:

```
KimlikServiceReference.KPSPublicSoapClient soapClient = new KimlikServiceReference.KPSPublicSoapClient(KimlikServiceReference.KPSPublicSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.KPSPublicSoap);
//KimlikServiceReference.TCKimlikNoDogrulaResponse response = soapClient.TCKimlikNoDogrulaAsync(TCKimlikNo, Ad, Soyad, DogumYili).Result;
bool result = soapClient.TCKimlikNoDogrula(TCKimlikNo, Ad, Soyad, DogumYili);
```